# For $Z$ independent of $X \sim N(0,t)$, $P[|Z-X|>a]\ge P[|X|>a]$?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

> Given that $X \sim N(0,t)$ and that $Z$ and $X$ are independent, show that for any $a>0$
>
> $$P[|Z-X|>a] \ge P[|X|>a]$$

*My approach was to prove this by first for when $Z $ is a constant function, extend the proof to when $Z $ is a simple function and then treat the general $Z $ as a limit of simple functions.* **I can do the first two steps but not the last.**

---

This is what I have done: since the density of $X$ is given by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}} $ which is symmetric about $0$ and has it's maximum at $0$, we see that $x \mapsto  P[|X-x|>a]$ is minimized at $x=0$. Thus the inequality holds when $Z$ is a constant random variable.

Now let $Z$ be such that it may take only two different values $a$ and $b$. Then

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
P[|Z-X|>a] &= \\
&= P[\{Z=a \} \cap \{|Z-X|>a\}]+P[\{Z=b \} \cap \{|Z-X|>a\}]  \\
&= P[\{Z=a \} \cap \{|a-X|>a\}]+P[\{Z=b \} \cap \{|b-X|>a\}]  \\
&= P[\{Z=a \}] P[ \{|a-X|>a\}]+P[\{Z=b \}] P[\{|b-X|>a\}] \\
&\ge  P[\{Z=a \}] P[ \{|X|>a\}]+P[\{Z=b \}] P[\{|X|>a\}] \\
&= P[\{|X|>a\}]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Where the last equality follows since $P[\{Z=a \}] + P[\{Z=b \}]=1$

Exactly the same proof works if $Z$ is a simple function taking $n$ different values.

> May I in some way by taking $Z $ to be a limit of simple functions extend this proof to general $Z $?

Note: $Z $ is of course assumed to be a random variable.

---

Much grateful for any help provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't $P[|Z-X|>a]=  E[ P(|Z-X|>a|Z) ]=E[g(Z)]$ where $g(z)=P[|z-X|>a]$, by the law of iterated expectations, a.k.a. Fubini's theorem?  As you point out, $g(z)\ge g(0)$, so the result follows immediately.